# context include sometimes returns list items in no particular order

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

In my ASP.Core 2.1 Web App, I have the 3 Models,
Profile which has Many Invoices,
Invoices which has Many Invoice Statuses

I retrieve them from the Db e.g.

```
_context.Invoices
.Include(st => st.InvoiceStatuses)
.FirstOrDefault(iv => iv.Id == invoiceId);
```

or sometimes

```
_context.Invoices
.Include(pr => pr.Profile)
.Include(st => st.InvoiceStatuses)
.FirstOrDefault(iv => iv.Id == invoiceId);
```

From this I expect to get a specific invoice and all related InvoiceStatuses in the order in which they were created(Db index order essentialy) 
Most of the time this is indeed the case. 
However, occasionally, I add a new Invoice record and initial invoice status and just a few of the invoices have their related Invoice Statuses List in a random / unexpected order. e.g index 10 12 18 16

I can get round this by breaking it down in to two queries for invoice and their statuses but was hoping someone could perhaps give some insight into what might be happening?

It would be easier if the problem happened consistently but if you delete a record (Sometimes needs to be a couple of records). You can then go on and add multiple records before the problem might potentially appear again.

I get the same problem when returning all Invoices.ToList() and each ones .Include related data but was trying to focus on the most simple scenario first.

I have not turned on LazyLoading or used Virtual keywords but not sure if this would matter.

Comment: Never assume an order when using `First`/`FirstOrDefault`. When selecting from a single table/index the order *should* be predictable, but as soon as you start querying across large, paged data sources, it is anything but predictable. Always use an explicit `OrderBy()` when using `First`.

Comment: As I have multiple Includes for other entities that are child lists, is it best to put orderby => id on the end of each one during _context read from db like so (where they are a list, and order matters)
        .Include(st => st.InvoiceStatuses).OrderBy(d => d.Id)

Comment: You should never assume order in a result set from a db. For clustered indices, one may assume the result is given in a specific order, but if you need an order on a query on a clustered index, chances are you're not using that index anyways. Includes are translated into left outer joins, which highly depend on the indices and the join strategy of the particular DB. Even then, EF might re-order the entries in the result set for some internal stuff (though I would doubt that, since they only implemented insert ordering on customer request)

Answer (score 0):

To continue from my comment....

`First`/`FirstOrDefault` should always be done with an OrderBy clause unless you truly don't care which one you will get.

Ordering in general is a display and business logic concern. Entities are a view of data.

In cases where you want to display data in order you should consider composing view models for the data to display, then use `.Select()` with applicable children in appropriate order. For instance if I want to select an invoice and list it's statuses in the order they were added. (assumed by the auto-increment Id order)

```
var invoice = _context.Invoices.OrderBy(x => x.Id)
    .Select(x => new InvoiceViewModel
    {
       Id = x.Id,
       // ... Fields the view needs to know about
       InvoiceStatuses = x.InvoiceStatuses.OrderBy(s => s.Id)
           .Select(s => s.StatusText)
           .ToList()
    }).FirstOrDefault();
```

So something like that would use the Invoice OrderBy to find the first applicable Invoice (by ID order) then select the fields we care about into a view model. For the Invoice Statuses it orders them by their Id and selects the StatusText to provide the view a list of Statuses as strings. Alternatively you could select an InvoiceStatusViewModel to return the Status Text, Status ID, etc. depending on what you view wanted.

Alternatively if you are selecting the data to be consumed on the spot for some business logic, you don't need to declare the view model classes, simply use anonymous types:

```
var invoice = _context.Invoices.OrderBy(x => x.Id)
    .Select(x => new 
    {
       x.Id,
       // ... Fields the view needs to know about
       InvoiceStatuses = x.InvoiceStatuses.OrderBy(s => s.Id)
           .Select(s => new 
           {
               s.Id,
               s.StatusText
           })
           .ToList()
    }).FirstOrDefault();
```

This gives you the data you might need to consume, in order, but as anonymous types you cannot return this data outside of the function scope such as to a view.

The technique of using `.Select()` to reduce results helps lead to more efficient queries as you can utilize all forms of aggregate methods so that rather than returning everything and then writing logic to iterate over, you can utilize `Max`, `Min`, `Sum`, `Any`, etc. to compose more efficient queries that run faster, and return less data over the wire.